# wrong calculatin of sha256 hash in android

Tags: java, android, sha

I have a problem generating a correct hash for a given string by android studio. I have read a lot of solutions without understanding how to convert it the right way.
I need the correct hash since i am making an HTTP request with it.

Here is my code in JAVA:

```
public String getHash(final String appSecret , final String sessionToken)throws NoSuchAlgorithmException ,UnsupportedEncodingException{

        String input = sessionToken + appSecret;
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.reset();

        byte[] byteData = digest.digest(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++){
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", 0xFF & byteData[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }
```

For an input like:

```
1130_11825_253402300799_1_1bcb4a27d42524de11325ec627b63878770a8651c0a0d8ddfc8fc06b92aea281634ff11f7d874c03851932304601439e
```

I need the exact output:

```
01a9d698f0587a25ad8ef56b0994ec0022364aff91d668a4b3a4b97c40167672
```

but i got a wrong output:

```
a60f61b5e9f832b153a91e8d2b1ffa28b9611b2d60c3669663cfe050ac8e28cc
```

I think my problem is how to read/print the string but i can't figure out how to correct it.
I know that an online hash calculator return a correct hash.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified `getHash` to take a a single `String`, I removed the call to `reset()` and you to finish `digest()`. I also prefer the [`for each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Like,

```
public static String getHash(final String msg) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(msg.getBytes());
        byte[] byteData = digest.digest();
        for (byte x : byteData) {
            String str = Integer.toHexString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(x));
            if (str.length() < 2) {
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(str);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String out = getHash("1130_11825_253402300799_1_1bcb4a27d42524de11325ec627b63878770a8651c0a0d8ddfc8fc06b92aea281634ff11f7d874c03851932304601439e");
    String expected = "01a9d698f0587a25ad8ef56b0994ec0022364aff91d668a4b3a4b97c40167672";
    System.out.println(out.equals(expected));
}
```

I get

```
true
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. If any of you want to use this code pay attention to the string you send. make sure it is without white spaces or without new lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Sha256Test {

    @Test
    public void sha256Test() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String out = hash256("1130_11825_253402300799_1_1bcb4a27d42524de11325ec627b63878770a8651c0a0d8ddfc8fc06b92aea281634ff11f7d874c03851932304601439e");
        String in  = "01a9d698f0587a25ad8ef56b0994ec0022364aff91d668a4b3a4b97c40167672";
        assertEquals(in, out);
    }

    private String hash256(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(data.getBytes());
        return bytesToHex(md.digest());
    }

    private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte byt : bytes) {
            result.append(Integer.toString((byt & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

See: https://gist.github.com/avilches/750151